# Poisson-like green functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

How can I verify that equation

$$\nabla ^2 f (r) = - \frac{e}{4 \pi \epsilon ^2} \delta (r-\epsilon)$$

in 3D has a solution of the form

$$f (r) = a - \frac{e}{4 \pi r} \theta (r-\epsilon) -\frac{e}{4 \pi \epsilon} \theta (\epsilon -r) \, .$$

The concept is I have a spherical shell with constant small radius $\epsilon$.

I know that the solution to the Poisson equation is $$G(\vec{r}-\vec{r}') = - \frac{1}{4 \pi |\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}$$ but I cannot combine it to verify this.

Comment: Don't bother with the Poisson equation. Use Gauss's law. The part for $r>\epsilon$ is pretty straight forward, and once you understand that case the rest will follow immediately.

Comment: @irwin. What's the derivative of a Heaviside Theta function? Can you take it from there?

Comment: Echoing @DanielSank's comment, forget about Greens functions. From a physics perspective, it is a consequence of [Newton's shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) that the electric potential is $V(r)=\frac{k_e Q}{r}$ outside the shell $r>\epsilon$; $V(r)=V_0$ constant inside the shell $r<\epsilon$; and continuous across the shell $r=\epsilon$. In other words, $V(r)=\frac{k_e Q}{r}\theta (r-\epsilon)+ \frac{k_e Q}{\epsilon} \theta (\epsilon-r)$. (Conventionally, we fix the potential to vanish at $r=\infty$.)