# How do you know when you need to use distributions to represent charge densities?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

I tried to solve a problem using Gauss' law in the following way.

Let's assume we have a spherical shell of radius $R$ with a charge $Q$ being homogenously distributed on its surface. I am trying to figure out the $E$-field generated by this assembly using Gauss' law.

It seems clear to me that for $r < R$, the $E$-field must equal 0. Now for $r > R$, one obtains
$$ E(r) \cdot 4\pi r^2 =  \oint_{\partial U_r} E \; dA = \int_{U_r} \nabla \cdot E\; dV = \int_{U_{r}} \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \; dV $$ 
But in this case, $\rho = 0$ everywhere except on $\partial U_r$, so we get
$$\int_{U_{r}} \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \; dV = \int_{\partial U_{r}} \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \; dV = 0$$
as the volume of $\partial U(r)$ is equal to 0. This was my original, incorrect solution.

If I got the hint provided in the comments right, it seems that the charge density should have the following form
$$\rho(r) = \delta(R-r)\cdot \frac{Q}{4\pi R^2}$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution, and that this will allow me to correctly calculate the $E$-field, yielding $$E(r) = \frac{Q}{4\epsilon_0 \pi r^2}, \quad r > R$$

All of this leads me to the following question: How does one recognize in general that one should use distributions instead of ordinary functions?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190612/2451

Comment: Don't you have to integrate over an *area* when considering the surface $\partial U_r$?

Comment: This is probably going to get closed for being an unacceptably crafted "homework like" question. It's also a "check my work" question which are normally rejected. Unfortunately I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: @DanielSank this is not a homework problem, it's a question that occurred to me when I read in my textbook about Gauss' law, and why is it unacceptably crafted? I dont think it qualifies as "check my work" either, because the new focus of the question is to explain why the need to work with distributions suddenly arises and how to recognize that need in general.

Comment: Whether or not the problem actually came from a homework assignment actually has nothing to do with the "homework-like" considerations on this site. It's a ridiculous misuse of terminology which, unfortunately, probably won't change any time soon. What is called "homework like" here just means that you're asking for help solving a specific problem. Anyway, whether or not I agree with it, this question is on the verge of being closed and mostly for being a mal-formed "homework like" question. Again, not my decision.

Comment: This approximation is just a mathematical one, kind of like two bodies being infinitely seperated and you might not have realised, but such mathematical approximations exist everywhere in physics. What you've is a theory, i.e. maxwell's equations. Now you use that theory to calculate certain things, it turns out that these calculations are ususally hard to evaluate as they might involve complex integrals etc. So we turn to limiting cases which are much easier to evaluate. So, obviously maxwell equations apply to real world and a strictly 2d surface isn't present in real world AFAIK

Comment: Maxwell equations strictly will always give you the wrong answer 2d surface.But when you evaluate the limit, i.e.what does this function actually tend towards, you're able to crack a number out.Now,this number is at times, the only solution we can crack out.Hence, we use it approximate to validate the theory as the ability to apply physics also depends on your abilities to solve differential equations.Hope this helps whenever you see things like point charge, line-charge etc.These approximations are present everywhere even in higher physics.Make these your friends as they do help you in need:)

Comment: I think the question in the edit is actually a good one: how do you recognize that you need to use distributions? I've edited the question to emphasize that aspect of it. (Naturally, without that, I would have added my close vote.) I've also deleted now-obsolete comments posted prior to the previous edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using distributions is a *trick* that people use whenever dealing with systems that do not have the required smoothness and integrability conditions and is in general only a mathematical technique to nevertheless solve those problems.

Maxwell equations, to start with, require both sides to be differentiable (at least a few times) and integrable and when you make use of the Gauß law you are implicitly accepting all the hypotheses and requirements it comes with. Amongst these, certain integrability and boundary conditions here and there.

Having a charge distribution that is always zero except, suddenly, on a set of zero measure (the boundary) is in fact one of those conditions that do not satisfy the requirements; also, in nature, things never become suddenly zero, rather they do so smoothly. Here the mathematical trick is that the Dirac delta has the nice property to give back smooth functions after being integrated over and therefore hides the problem away. The correct way to deal with such exercises is to extend the domain of definition of the Maxwell equations on the dual set of functions (i. e. the distributions), thus allowing for less strict differentiability conditions in order to allow formal manipulations with Dirac deltas and so on. But unless you are attending classes in algebraic quantum field theory for mathematicians, physicists never do that and cope with the mathematical tricks as long as the solutions is correct.

Comment: perfect . +1  ;]